# Python urllib-html parse

Tags: python, file, parsing, xpath, lxml

Question about parsing web-site:
My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import urllib2
import re
# Parse Web
from lxml import html
import requests
def parse():
    try:

        output = open('proba.xml','w')
        page = requests.get('http://www.rts.rs/page/tv/sr/broadcast/22/RTS+1.html')
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        parse =  tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramTime"]/text()|//div[@class="ProgramName"]/text()|//a[@class="recnik"]/text()')

        for line in parse:
            clean = line.strip()
            if clean:
                print clean     
    except:
        pass

parse()
```

My question is how can I write this result to file, when I try with this:

```
print >> output, line
```

I got only 6 first lines into file.
With this code:

```
output.write(line)
```

Same thing, so can you help me with this issue. 
What I wanan is to output parsed content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having trouble replicating the problem.  Here is what I did...

```
import sys
import os
import urllib2
import re
from lxml import html
import requests

def parse():
    output = open('proba.xml','w')
    page = requests.get('http://www.rts.rs/page/tv/sr/broadcast/22/RTS+1.html')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    p = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramTime"]/text()|//div[@class="ProgramName"]/text()|//a[@class="recnik"]/text()')
    for line in p:
        clean = line.strip()
        if clean:
            output.write(line.encode('utf-8')+'\n')  # the \n adds a line break
    output.close()
parse()
```

I think you are getting a unicode related error when writing to the file, but because you put everything in a `try` block and let the error pass silently you aren't getting feedback!

Try typing `import this` in a terminal.  You will get the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  One aphorism is *"Errors should never pass silently."*

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
    with file('proba.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines([line.strip() for line in parse]

Put this in place of for line in parse: clean = *** and remove the declaration output = *** above and no need for output.write again. Sorry if am not clearer am typing this on a mobile phone.